# Topological property of an algebraic stack and its presentation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, algebraic-stacks

I started to learn algebraic stacks this January. I found there are several properties of algebraic stacks which are defined in terms of their underlying topological spaces, for example, connectedness, irreducibility, quasi-compactness, and so on. Compared to properties which are local in smooth topology, I found those properties defined as properties of the underlying topological space especially hard to prove, since descent methods sometimes don't work.

For connectedness, proposition 4.14 in Deligne and Mumford's paper "The irreducibility of the space of curves of given genus" asserts that a connected algebraic stack $\mathcal{X}$ of finite type over a field $k$ has a smooth presentation $X\to \mathcal{X}$ such that $X$ is also connected.

For quasi-compactness, exercise 3.3.21 in Jarod Alper's "Stacks and Moduli" says that a quasi-compact algebraic stack $\mathcal{X}$ has a smooth presentation by an affine scheme.

For irreducibility, I wonder if there is an analogous claim. Also, I am not sure about the proof of the above two claims, but I feel this should be relevant to the fact that any presentation of an algebraic stack defines the same topology on that stack, which comes from the fact that faithfully flat locally of finite presentation maps are universally open, and this is in Stacks Project Section 99.4.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your post does not include an actual question; could you maybe add emphasis on what you're asking? In addition, the stacks projects is a constantly changing document, and the stable reference system is via [tags](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags), not sections.

Comment: See [Lemma 106.3.1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DR4) of the stacks project. It shows in particular that any algebraic stack with a cover by an irreducible scheme is irreducible

Comment: You did not state Prop 4.14 from Deligne-Mumford correctly!

Comment: Here is something interesting: the stack quotient of the coordinate axes in the plane by the involution is irreducible, smooth locally on the coarse moduli space, yet it is not unibranch.